# Concatenating single quotes around a section of a select statement

Tags: sql, datetime, concatenation

The following is a section of my select statement

```
CAST(Table.field AS datetime) AS newDate
```

As you would expect, it returns something like the following

```
1/1/1900  2:45:00 PM
```

However, I need it to return that same value inside single quotes as seen below. But I am having a really hard time for the syntax of this, with a cast statement, with a column renaming. Hopefully you guys could be of some help?

```
'1/1/1900  2:45:00 PM'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the value to a varchar and concatenate them:

```
''''+cast(cast(table.field as date) as varchar(255))+''''
```

You might want to investigate `convert` to have better control over the format of the resulting date.

That used the SQL Server method for concatenation.  In other databases, you might use `||` or the function `concat`.

Comment: wow, i would have never thought to do this. lemme give it a shot!

Comment: that worked! thanks a bunch! 9 minutes till i can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can append single quotes like this.

```
chr(39)||CAST(Table.field AS datetime) AS newDate||chr(39)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Chr(39) + CAST(CAST(table.field AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(255)) + Chr(39)`

For an easier read.